# How to group exception messages from AssertJ for better reporting?

Tags: java, automation, testng, allure, assertj

At first, we used TestNG Asserts for all our automation test validations which can throw a predefined error message. The allure report, groups the failures based on the error messages making it very easy to read and understand.

Recently we started to use AssertJ to perform our test validations. This is an awesome framework, but it throws very long exception messages (has more information). The problem is that now my allure report cannot group all these failures, hence reporting them individually making it very hard to read.

I know that we can over-ride AssetJ error messages, but I don't know how to do it for my custom class object field validations. Please guide me on this. Thank you.

To put my question more simply, my current exception message is as below 
`UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "type" (class com.data.files.Files), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "name", "hash", "id", "versionId"])
 at [Source: {"id":"2yI94ibmVPI","name":"File01.html","versionId":"xzmnggrX6iQ","hash":"39252a3c0577a4d28da144b414871264","type":"FILE"}; line: 1, column: 1190] (through reference chain: com.data.files.Files["type"])`

but what I need is just the below message (remaining info can be part of stack trace) 
 
 
`UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "type" (class com.data.files.Files)`

what is the easiest way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to have smaller error messages in AssertJ, they are baked in the framework.

Comment: Okay, I accept there are no easy way to do this. Is there a hard way to get this done? This is a deal breaker for our project. (We use TestNG for execution)

Comment: you can catch the AssertionError, get the exception message, change it as you see fit and rethrow a new AssertionError.
Not great but should work.

Comment: thanks for that brillant work @JoelCostigliola I just finished to read the source). I it seem to have a future plan to do so with Assertions.useRepresentation( ..) but this is not done for all the format, is there a performance issue that prevent to do so ? Except the fact there is formating everywhere and that it involve a serious time consuming effort to provide hook or templating system. anyway the framework is sugar candy I have good time to use it thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QAF](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) which provides webelement specific [assertion and verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) aka checkpoint. If there is unexpected exception, in report you will find summary. It also [reports](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html#test-details) each checkpoint with automatic capture screenshot on failure with meaningful message along with [error analysis](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html#error-analysis). Another benefit is while using assertion/verification you don't need to put waits QAF automatically handles it.